# Understanding Albinism probability (Sheldon Ross)

Tags: probability

This is a question from Sheldon Ross's book 8th ed (Chapter 3, Q 61) -

> Genes relating to albinism are denoted by A and a. Only those people who receive the a gene from
> both parents will be albino. Persons having the gene pair A, a are normal in appearance and,
> because they can pass on the trait to their offspring, are called carriers. Suppose that a normal
> couple has two children, exactly one of whom is an albino. Suppose that the nonalbino child mates
> with a person who is known to be a carrier for albinism.

> (a) What is the probability that their first offspring is an albino?

> (b) What is the conditional probability that their second offspring is an albino given that their firstborn is not?

**My solution process (part (a))**

The normal couple can be any one of $(Aa, Aa), (Aa, aA), (Aa, aa)$ or $(aA, aa)$. The first and second combination will give gene pairs as $(AA, Aa, aA, aa)$ and third and fourth will give $(aa, aa, Aa, Aa)$. The non albino will not be $aa$, so when this nonalbino child mates with another carrier (without loss of generality, lets assume $Aa$), I will get $(6+4)$x$4 = 40$ possible offspring gene pairs ($AA-12, aa-8$ and remaining $Aa$ or $aA$). So I have 8 outcomes for getting an albino child out of 40, which gives the probability as $1/5$.

**Another solution**

I got a solution to first part [here](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Ewsw/F14/107/s02final-solutions.pdf). The answer say that the nonalbino child (who mates with another carrier) is the offspring of two people having gene pairs $A,a$. I don't understand why they both have to be the carriers? If one of the parent is nonalbino (having $A,a$ or $A,A$ or $a,A$) and other is albino (having $a,a$), then also they can have one albino $(a,a)$ and one non albino $(A,A$ or $A,a)$ child. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: The question doesn't stipulate any probabilistic assumptions, such as "the probability of passing on an A gene is 20%" or whatever.  So it cannot be answered (unless the answer is either 100% or 0%).

Comment: @DanielV I don't think that kind of assumption is necessary. You can assume that all events i.e., any gene pair is equally likely to be in an offspring.

Comment: They both have to be carriers because $A$ is dominant. If one of the parents were not a carrier then there is no way for an $a,a$ pair to occur.

Comment: @JohnDouma Nowhere in the question it is given that A is dominant. And if one parent is $A,a$ (carrier) and other is $a,a$ (albino), can you not get $a,a$ ?

Comment: We are told the parents of the non-albino are normal which means they are not $a, a$. The non-albino, by definition, is not $a, a$ and his spouse is a carrier, which is not $a, a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know both parents of the non-albino child must be carriers because they produced an $a,a$ offspring. The possibilities for the non-albino child are therefore, $$A,a$$
$$a,A$$  $$A,A$$

This means there is a $\frac{2}{3}$ probability that the non-albino child is a carrier. Each of the non-albino and his spouse donates an allele independently so we are looking for the product of the probabilities that each donates an $a$.

$P(\text{non-albino donates a})=P(\text{he is a carrier})P(\text{donates a}|\text{he is a carrier})=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$

$P(\text{spouse donates a})=\frac{1}{2}$ because we know she is a carrier.

Therefore, the answer to the first question is $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$

To get the second part you can use Bayes' theorem to compute $P(\text{second is}|\text{first is not})$ and by noticing that $P(\text{first is not})=\frac{5}{6}$